# Haskell - Coding 'maximum' without actually using the function [beginner]

Tags: haskell

Complete the following function definition:

```
    -- maxi x y returns the maximum of x and y
```

I'm supposed to complete this task *without* using the 'maximum' function in Haskell.

```
maxi :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
maxi x y
 |x > y = x
 |y > x = y
```

Then I don't understand how to proceed. How do I test if the code is valid? And does it look somewhat correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can test the function by *calling* it (yourself or with a test library, like `QuickCheck`). We can for example store the source code in a file (named `test.hs`):

```
-- test.hs

maxi :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
maxi x y
 |x > y = x
 |y > x = y
```

Then we can for example start a GHC interactive session, by using the `ghci` command and load the file passing the file name as a parameter. We can then call it:

```
$ ghci test.hs
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> maxi 2 9
9
*Main> maxi 3 5
5
*Main> maxi 7 2
7
```

Is it correct? **no**. There is a case here that is not covered: in case `x` and `y` are the same, then it will raise an error:

```
*Main> maxi 7 7
*** Exception: test.hs:(4,1)-(6,13): Non-exhaustive patterns in function maxi
```

We can fix it by using `otherwise` as last check, which will always be `True` (in fact it is an alias for `True`). You can see `otherwise` as an `else`:

```
-- test.hs

maxi :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
maxi x y
 | x > y = x
 | otherwise = y
```